# CoreStore update relationships by deleting objects via transaction.edit does not work

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, corestore

I would like to update my core data object by deleting some objects in relationships.

I know CoreStore provides few method update and delete. My question is can I delete by using update functionality?

```
let john: MyPersonEntity ...
jane.removeFromFriends(john) // Removing john form NSSet

CoreStore.perform(
    asynchronous: { (transaction) -> Void in

        let jane = transaction.edit(jane)! // Assuming that this is a proxy and context will be saved with no john.

    },
    completion: { _ in }
)
```

Or do I need to remove john like this from the relationships.

```
let john: MyPersonEntity = jane.getJohnObject() // Returns john object from NSSet.

CoreStore.perform(
    asynchronous: { (transaction) -> Void in
        transaction.delete(john)
    },
    completion: { _ in }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short no, as John is a Entinity. John needs to be deleted. There is no further action necessary if the relation uses the default nullify rule.

Comment: am I right that transaction.edit(jane) just return some jane object with the properties which were instantiated during create or import process and if I need to update jane this is not enough just to write transaction.edit(jane)

Comment: also can I delete object first and then import some objects at the same CoreStore.perform(
    asynchronous: { (transaction)?